# PHP redirect to page on form submit based on select

Tags: php, select, authentication, html-table, submit

I am trying to get PHP to read my select options as variables and then echo out a particular page based on the users choice.

The login system is functional but only logs me into one page.

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <table cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td>Email: </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Event: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="event">
                    <option><?php echo $title?></option>
                    <option><?php echo $title2?></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button class="button" type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />Login</button> 
</form>

<?php

     if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {

                $pdo = getPdo();

                $statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM awdawda WHERE email=:email;');

                $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);

                $statement->execute();

                $data = $statement->fetch();

                $pdo = null;

                if (!empty($data)) {
                    $dbemail = $data['email'];
                    $dbpassword = $data['password'];
                    $dbfullname = $data['fullname'];

                    if ($password == $dbpassword) {
                        $_SESSION['fullname'] = $dbfullname;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                        if ($_POST['event']) {
                            $event1=$title;
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://awda/adwa/awd1.php" </script>';
                        }

                        if ($_POST['event']) {
                            $event2=$title2;
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://awdaw/awda/adwa.php" </script>';
                        }

                    }

                    echo '<div style="padding: 10px;">Login Failed: Password Incorrect</div>';
                }

                echo '<div style="padding: 10px;">User not found</div>';
            }

?>
```

That is the code I am using to login with. I left out what was above it since it all works fine right now.

Comment: are the values of `$title` and `$title2` static?

Comment: theyre being called from a database, displaying the title of the event. so no? there is an admin panel that allows for them to be edited so the pages are reusable.

Comment: in this condition how you match which title should print. because your `<option>` tag doesn't have any value so in every condition you don't have value in `$_POST['event']` so no `if` will get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give value to the `options` of your `select` tag

```
<select name="event">
    <option value="value1"><?php echo $title?></option>
    <option value="value2"><?php echo $title2?></option>
</select>
```

and have to update your php logic according to these value

```
if ($_POST['event'] == "value1") {
    $event1=$title;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://awda/adwa/awd1.php" </script>';
}

if ($_POST['event'] == "value2") {
    $event2=$title2;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://awdaw/awda/adwa.php" </script>';
}
```

Comment: Ok, We assign value then how do you identify where should it redirect? `values` are fetching from `DB` you can not check them for static values

Comment: `theyre being called from a database, displaying the title of the event. so no?`. This is what user say about values

Comment: @BrendonWells : if you have three values in your drop down then you check three times and if you have `n` values then check `nth` times. `lol`. Great way of coding. God help you.

Comment: @SazzadurRahman: php have `header` function so no need to write `JS` code for redirecting.

Comment: @BrendonWells You should use `foreach` loop to generate your drop-down box, if it fetched from DB

Comment: @urfusion: I know that, but I want to provide a quick solution for his problem.

Comment: @SazzadurRahman : `You should use foreach loop to generate your drop-down box, if it fetched from DB`. How many time you check the value of `option` with `static values` that you suggested. Suppose `if you have three values in your drop down then you check three times and if you have n values then check nth times`?

Comment: @urfusion: As I don't know his database structure so I'm not sure does he has any field for the values of his `option` tag. I'm just pointing out the mistakes he has made. If he is smart enough he can improve the code quality a lot by avoiding the mistake form next time.